# Materialize SASS compiling

Tags: node.js, express, sass

It's the very first time I am using Materialize and I have never been in touch with SASS. I have installed the materialize-sass package using `npm install materialize-sass --save`. I want to define a color set and compile the CSS file then.

How can I compile my SCSS files after editing the _variables.sccs now so that it will output the CSS file in my public/stylesheets folder?

Comment: What are you to compile the sass? (Gulp? Grunt? Webpack dev server?) if you haven't added a configuration yet, you can use quesadilla (a **node-sass** express middleware) it watches your sass files and autocompiles when you edit

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @DenisTsoi. I have got two questions. 1. Is it being executed every time an user visits my express website as this is middleware? 2. I have installed the materialize-sass using NPM and the scss files are located inside of the node_modules/materialize-sass folder, can I leave them there or should I move them into the public folder?

Comment: 1. if you use quesadilla middleware, then don't use it in production. it's  better to compile straight to css (and minify) in that situation.

2. if you import materialize-sass within your main.scss, then it will be included within your compiled main.css `@import "node_modules/materialise-sass";`

Answer (score 0):

In the end I have used Koala which is a GUI application for compiling SASS / SCSS files.

Answer (score 0):

Koala App provides GUI (graphical user interface) for automatic compiling of LESS, Sass, Compass and CoffeeScript. It’s also multiplatform as it gets, with clients for Windows, Mac and Linux